# Why the value of k[5] element gets instantiated with 0?

Tags: c

Well the problem i have with this piece of code is that, when i debug it the value of the 5th element in k array gets instantiated with the value 0.Can anyone explain why this happens? It would be good if you could debug it too!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
main ()
{
    int k[5]={3,1,7,2,6};
    float d=0;
    int t =3;
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
    if (k[5]>t)
        d+=k[i];
    else
      d++;
    }
     d/=2;
    printf("%f\n",d);
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Arrays in C (and most languages) start with indexes at 0, not 1.

Comment: k[5] is the sixth element.  k[0] is the firsts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in C are "0" indexed.  That means that the first element of k is k[0], the second element is k[1], all the way up to the fifth element of k being k[4].

You act on this properly in your for loop, where you go from i = 0 through i = 4 (i.e. "i < 5").

k[5] is coming out as 0 because it happens that that area of memory that's right after your array is currently set to 0.  It could be set to any value at all - it's completely arbitrary.
By looking at k[5], you're looking outside of the area allocated to your array, and are looking at a part of memory you shouldn't look at.  In a managed programming language, that line of code would throw an exception, because you're doing something you absolutely shouldn't.

Comment: Well,its behaviour is like this.I am starting by adding a watch for k[5] element.Then, i start debugging and the value of k[5] element is a totally random number...like it should be. But running the next line, that means the line with the command **float d;** then some magic happens and the k[5] becomes 0! Then,the first iteration runs, but exactly after the first iteration the k[5] becomes again random ...like 1032233295!! @Scott Mermelstein

Comment: @johnjohn, *anything* can happen when you look at `k[5]`.  It *doesn't really exist*.  You are aliasing some other data.  In this case it sounds like `&k[5]` might be the same as `&d` and you're seeing the data in `d`.  You shouldn't rely on that behaviour, though.  Why are you worried about it?

Comment: I agree completely with Carl.  What you see when you access k[5] doesn't matter, because it's not something you should be seeing.  It can be absolutely anything, because you're looking at memory you shouldn't look at.  C is powerful, but at the same time dangerous precisely for things like this - it lets you look at memory you don't "own", and you have to be sure not to do so.  k[5] looks at just some random place in memory.  You shouldn't ever look at it.

Comment: Incidentally, in your posted code, do you perhaps want the line `if (k[5] > t)` to instead show `if (k[i] > t)`?  We've all been correcting your invalid access of memory, when maybe we should be asking: What do you want your code to be doing, anyway?  Even if you did some valid code, such as `if (k[4] > t)`, it would not make sense - your `if` clause would always evaluate to the same value - in this case, `true`.

Comment: I am not worried.A little confused because this happens every time i am debugging this programm with the exact steps i already described..Thanks for your help @Carl

Comment: In this case it's probably not "random".  I'm sure it's reproducible for a given binary, for example.  But it might vary from build to build, for example.  If you're trying to investigate what your implementation *does*, it might be enlightening.  Check what `&d` and `&k[5]` are, maybe that will tell you something.

Comment: One thing, just to be totally sure you're understanding:  If you're trying to access the fifth element of your array - the one that right now is set to 6, you want to use k[4], **not** k[5].

Comment: @johnjohn Your issue with the value magically becoming `0` is because you're reading in to the float. Most C implementations store automatic variables on a stack. When the `int k[5]` is the top value on the stack, then `k[5]` is garbage data from whatever was in the memory before. However when you make a float, it gets pushed to the top of the stack. If you've ever tried to `printf("%d",float);`, you'll notice it prints `0`. This points towards k[5] reading in to the float. Like others have stated though: this is **undefined behavior**. Don't count on it.

Comment: @Aslai, `printf("%d", d)` (I assume you meant `d`) might not print 0.  Some systems use separate varargs stacks for integer and floating point types.

Comment: I guess, if we really wanted to check if the "random" numbers are related to the float, we could do the following: `printf("d = %f, k[5] = %f", d, *(float *)&k[5]);`  If that _is_ the memory we're illegally looking at, it will print out the same values for d and the typecast k[5].  Or for that matter, `printf("d's address: %x, k[5]'s address: %x", &d, &k[5]);`

Answer (score 7):

`k[5]` doesn't exist - it would be the *6th* element of `k`, not the 5th.  Arrays in C are zero-indexed.  That means `k` has elements `k[0]`, `k[1]`, `k[2]`, `k[3]`, and `k[4]`, and that's it.

You've caused undefined behaviour, so anything could happen.

Comment: please take a look at the comment below.